# lldb type summary provider - SBProcess is invalid

Tags: types, lldb, provider, summary

I wrote a lldb type summary provider for wstring with 16bit wchar on Ubuntu 16.04.

Things work fine if I manually do the following in lldb:

```
(lldb) script import mytypes
(lldb) type summary add -F mytypes.wstring_SummaryProvider "std::__1::wstring"
```

I tried to make things easier with auto-loading by adding the following to .lldbinit:

```
script import mytypes
type summary add -F mytypes.wstring_SummaryProvider "std::__1::wstring"
```

Then I got a failure of "SBProcess is invalid" when printing a wstring variable.

My type summary function has the following, which I believe is where the error is encountered:

```
content = lldb.process.ReadMemory(bufferAddr, byteCount, error)
```

Maybe this is because "process" is not assigned yet when the type summary is added during auto-loading?

Does anyone know how to make auto loading work for my script?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enrico already answered this on lldb-dev:

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2016-September/011236.html

but for those following along here:

The `lldb.process`, `lldb.thread` etc variables are only meant as a convenience for use in the interactive python interpreter, and not for Python code that gets run for breakpoints, data formatters, commands, etc.

It doesn't make sense in a multi-threaded debugger to try to present a global notion of "current thread" to any bits of script code that might get run.  Instead, each context in which the script gets run knows the process/thread/frame that are relevant to it.  In the case of data formatters, they always get passed the value they are working on, and that knows the relevant process through the `SBValue.GetProcess()` API.